# SQLITE_RANGE: bind or column index out of range

Tags: node.js, sqlite

I'm trying to insert rows into a database and I've tried to simplify my code as much as possible, but I'm still getting the error 'SQLITE_RANGE: bind or column index out of range'

```
const sqlite3 = require('sqlite3').verbose();
let db = new sqlite3.Database(':memory:', (err) => {
  if (err) {
    return console.error(err.message);
  }
  console.log('Connected to the in-memory SQlite database.');
});
db.serialize(function(){
    db.run('CREATE TABLE parks ' +
        '(' +
        'Name text' +
        ')'
    );
});
csv.fromPath("parks.csv", {renameHeaders : true, headers : [, 
    'Name',
    ]})
 .on("data", function(data){
     query = "INSERT INTO parks VALUES ('Arbutus_Village_Park')"
     db.run(query, ['C'], function(err) {
         if (err) {
             return console.log(err.message);
         }
     });
})
```

Could someone please point out something that I might be missing out on? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your syntax on `db.run`, see [API documentation](https://github.com/mapbox/node-sqlite3/wiki/API#databaserunsql-param--callback).

Your code fails because you try to pass `'C'` as a bound parameter, but the query contains no placeholders.